# In Jenkins: How to Run NPM install , npm run and Npm run proxy

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Need to create a Jenkins Pipeline  , which needs to do the following

1. perform npm install
2. Run below in parallel

   npm run start

   npm run proxy

Any ideas !!

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: do you have any syntax that can be tried ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works in jenkins pipeline ( for windows)
bat 'npm install'
bat 'start npm run start'
the start directive will run the npm run start in background